# When trying to access scripts attached to a prefab, how to solve NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

How can i solve this problem am trying to call function that is attached to a prefab in my scene, am using C# unity engine, editor lts3.3.1

Here is my Code, the DialogCall class in its function  OnTriggerEnter() will call the TriggerDialogue() function of DialogueTrigger class

Codes for DialogueCall

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DialogueCall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DialogueTrigger dialogueTrigger;
    public GameObject[] gameObject;
    void Start(){
        dialogueTrigger = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Dialog").GetComponent<DialogueTrigger>();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            for(int a=0;a<5;a++){
                gameObject[a].SetActive(false);
            }
            dialogueTrigger.TriggerDialogue();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Codes for DialogueTrigger

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue ()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }

}
```

The dialogue TriggerDialogue() function is attached to a prefab object on a button to be clicked to launch dialogue in my game.

Thanks!

I expect the TriggerDialogue() function of DialogueTrigger class to be called when the Player collides with my object. But am getting the error**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DialogueCall.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Scripts/DialogueCall.cs:20)**

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `gameObject` as variable name first of all, that is already a Unity reserved keyboard.

If the error is what is is, then it should be one element of the array doesn't have a gameobject assigned.

I would revise how you approach this problem.

Also prefabs aren't a thing once the scene is started, they become regular Objects.
Prefab is a unity editor concept